# Как удалить несколько строк в таблице mysql?

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

В таблице есть даннные такого вида:
`<ul>
 <li><a href="#nav1">Произвольный текст</a></li>
 <li><a href="#nav2">Произвольный текст</a></li>
 <li><a href="#nav3">Произвольный текст</a></li>
...
</ul>`
Подскажите как удалить регуляркой их все?

Comment: Эти данные находятся в одном поле? Вы подразумеваете текстовые строки или строки таблицы?

Comment: Я неточно сформулировал вопрос: есть таблица, в ней строки, в определенном поле которых содержится искомый текст.

Comment: А mysql тут при чем? Чем удалять собрались через js или парсер на каком то языке? Конкретики бы